# Programmatically create FTP account

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, ftp

I'm looking to programmatically create FTP accounts on my website.  It needs to be able to:

- Issue username and password
- Give FTP access to a specific folder with a filesize limit
- Delete the FTP account

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: yep, here you go : http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/developing-for-ftp/how-to-use-managed-code-c-to-create-an-ftp-authentication-provider-with-dynamic-ip-restrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380769/Creating-an-FTP-Server-in-Csharp-with-IPv6-Support) example from codeproject?
Seems very useful and its explained step by step and you have a free source code to see it. Hope it helps!